# Displaying picture from the gallery on image button

Tags: android

I have 7 small image buttons. I want that when you click one, you are able to select a picture from the Gallery and display it on the button. The problem is with big pictures like 4.5 Mb from the camera, every picture I add takes 50 Mb ram, and on the 3rd picture it crashes with outOfMemory.   When I remove the `setImage` on the button so I only save my pictures for later it works.

```
private void setPicture(ImageButton button, Intent data){
    Uri imageUrl = data.getData();

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUrl);

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), image);

        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        pictures.add(stream.toByteArray());

        //button.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid keeping the full, large bitmap in memory just to show a small sample of it on a button - load a downsampled version instead.

You should check out this official Android Guide:

**Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently**

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html